# How to save data with formats and values in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, paste, vba

I am trying to save data from sheet("Billing") to another sheets("Bill_Register") with formats and values not formulas. Pasteformats and pastevalues are working separately not together. Please suggest me a better VBA. Thanks in advance.[image]

```
Sub Save_invoice()

Dim i As Integer
Dim last As Long
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range


last = Sheets("Bill_Register").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Sheets("Billing").Range("A1:J42")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Bill_Register").Range("A" & last + 2)

rng.Copy
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
rng.Copy
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have merged cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have merged cells and use xlPasteValues then an error will occur.
use variant array.

```
Sub Save_invoice()

Dim i As Integer
Dim last As Long
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim vDB

last = Sheets("Bill_Register").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Sheets("Billing").Range("A1:J42")
vDB = rng '<~~ set array
Set rng2 = Sheets("Bill_Register").Range("A" & last + 2)

rng.Copy
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
rng2.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB '<~~ get value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If `rng` and `rng2` have the exactly same size (rows and columns) then you can use this to get the values:

`rng2.Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value`

Some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:B2")
    Set rng2 = Range("D2:E3")

    rng2.Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the number formatting etc. but not necessarily the fill colour etc. then you could use:

```
Rng.Copy
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to copy twice, once it is in the clipboard it is there till replaced.

Paste the values first then the format:

```
Sub Save_invoice()

Dim i As Integer
Dim last As Long
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range


last = Sheets("Bill_Register").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Sheets("Billing").Range("A1:J42")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Bill_Register").Range("A" & last + 2)

rng.Copy
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


End Sub
```